# How to delete parent array JSON string and leave an child array JSON string?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like this ( it has an array inside an array like the code below )

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "40",
            "memo_kondisi": "OKe lah",
            "id_kondisi": "010118",
            "total_row": "2",
            "nilai_temuan": "10.000.000",
            "nilai_potensi_kerugian": "9.000.000",
            "data_sebab": [
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "id_sebab": "0202",
                    "total_row_b": "2",
                    "memo_sebab": "sebab 1",
                    "data_rekomendasi": [
                       {
                        "id": "14",
                        "id_rekomendasi": "",
                        "nilai_rekomendasi": "0",
                        "memo_rekomendasi": "",
                        "data_tindak_lanjut": [
                            {
                                "id": "20",
                                "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "21",
                                "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                            }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "14",
                            "id_rekomendasi": "",
                            "nilai_rekomendasi": "0",
                            "memo_rekomendasi": "",
                            "data_tindak_lanjut": [
                                {
                                    "id": "20",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "21",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted the JSON array to look like this: 
**Expected Result**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "40",
            "memo_kondisi": "OKe lah",
            "id_kondisi": "010118",
            "total_row": "2",
            "nilai_temuan": "10.000.000",
            "nilai_potensi_kerugian": "9.000.000",
            "data_sebab": [{
                                "id": "20",
                                "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "21",
                                "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                            },
                                {
                                    "id": "20",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "21",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                }
                            ]        
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the array parent will be removed and will leave a child array, it's like `push array` but its reverse and it will delete the parent JSON array. Any suggestion ? Since i had no idea how to delete the parent array, i didn't give any *minimal code* that i made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 4 nested arrays, so in order to flatten the middle two tiers, you'll have to execute 4 nested loops.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/XWpZB

```
$data = json_decode($json, true)['data'];

$result = [];

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    // copy top tier
    $copy = $datum;
    // clear children
    $copy['data_sebab'] = null;

    foreach ($datum['data_sebab'] as $sebab) {
        foreach ($sebab['data_rekomendasi'] as $rekomendasi) {
            foreach ($rekomendasi['data_tindak_lanjut'] as $tindak_lanjut) {
                // copy leaf child
                $copy['data_sebab'] []= $tindak_lanjut;
            }
        }
    }

    // nest last leaf under top tier
    $result['data'] []= $copy;
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: wow , this is looks good, i tried the that you gave, and i got some error.

Comment: @Gagantous well, I posted [the demo](https://3v4l.org/XWpZB) using your provided data, so if you're getting an error, then you're using data from a different question...

Comment: @Gagantous your link is dead - can you post an 3v4l link that shows the error?

Comment: @Gagantous you've got trailing commas on lines 69 and 136. See now with those removed: https://3v4l.org/t0kHA

Comment: OMG, GENIUS, Thank you so much, God Bless you @JeffPucket

Comment: I am sorry @Jeffpucket, i accidently press the reward bountie to the wrong user... I didnt see the user carefully..  i am sorry...

Comment: @Gagantous I noticed you made a mistake.  I don't think it can easily be undone so instead i set a bounty on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070604/rowspan-if-the-some-td-contain-same-id-using-jquery-json-data which I will award to your answer there in 23 hrs so you will get your reputation back.

Comment: @gagantous haha no worries!

Comment: @JeffPuckett I will award to your answer there in 23 hrs :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  If the sample data is in `data.json` then the command

```
$ jq -M '.data[].data_sebab |= map(.data_rekomendasi[].data_tindak_lanjut[])' data.json
```

produces

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "40",
      "memo_kondisi": "OKe lah",
      "id_kondisi": "010118",
      "total_row": "2",
      "nilai_temuan": "10.000.000",
      "nilai_potensi_kerugian": "9.000.000",
      "data_sebab": [
        {
          "id": "20",
          "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
          "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
          "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
          "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
          "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
        },
        {
          "id": "21",
          "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
          "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
          "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
          "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
          "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've put the example into this snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/N5iLlR-MPi - I do not see an error. Does your input differ from the sample?

Comment: I am trying to use you suggest command $jq -M but in your sniper there is no $jq -M. What's that?

Comment: The [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) describes the options but to answer your question: `-M` prevents jq from generating colored output.  It's not relevant in on jqplay.org but I always use it so that I won't be surprised by coloring codes when copying commands between scripts.   Here is what the manual has to say: `By default, jq outputs colored JSON if writing to a terminal. You can force it to produce color even if writing to a pipe or a file using -C, and disable color with -M.`

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the array using `json_decode()` then re-assign the array:

```
# Presumably you have this somewhere as an array already or in a string
$json = '{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "40",
            "memo_kondisi": "OKe lah",
            "id_kondisi": "010118",
            "total_row": "2",
            "nilai_temuan": "10.000.000",
            "nilai_potensi_kerugian": "9.000.000",
            "data_sebab": [
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "id_sebab": "0202",
                    "total_row_b": "2",
                    "memo_sebab": "sebab 1",
                    "data_rekomendasi": [
                        {
                            "id": "14",
                            "id_rekomendasi": "",
                            "nilai_rekomendasi": "0",
                            "memo_rekomendasi": "",
                            "data_tindak_lanjut": [
                                {
                                    "id": "20",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "21",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';
# Decode
$array = json_decode($json,true);
# Reassign
$array['data'][0]['data_sebab'] = $array['data'][0]['data_sebab'][0]['data_rekomendasi'][0]['data_tindak_lanjut'];
# Write back to json
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: it's just give me `data` array only... not the `data_sebab` nor other array

Comment: I will double check, but I tested it out and my script gives the exact array you have demonstrated in your example of what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: The script I have supplied is identical to what your outcome is supposed to be.

Comment: okay it, works, but when  `data_rekomendasi` have two array ( in my question i just give 1  array ) it give only the first key. The second key value didnt appear @Rasclatt

Comment: i have edited my question @Rasclatt, how do increment the `$array['data']['increment key value']['data_sebab'] `, iknow i have to use foreach, but how do i do that  ?

Comment: So that you have 4 (or more) arrays under `data_sebab`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this using ES6 [**for...of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement **:**

The `for-of` loop introduced with `ES6` allows for iterating over an array (or any iterable) in a succinct fashion similar to how we can iterate over the keys of an object using `for-in`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "40",
            "memo_kondisi": "OKe lah",
            "id_kondisi": "010118",
            "total_row": "2",
            "nilai_temuan": "10.000.000",
            "nilai_potensi_kerugian": "9.000.000",
            "data_sebab": [
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "id_sebab": "0202",
                    "total_row_b": "2",
                    "memo_sebab": "sebab 1",
                    "data_rekomendasi": [
                       {
                        "id": "14",
                        "id_rekomendasi": "",
                        "nilai_rekomendasi": "0",
                        "memo_rekomendasi": "",
                        "data_tindak_lanjut": [
                            {
                                "id": "20",
                                "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "21",
                                "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                            }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "14",
                            "id_rekomendasi": "",
                            "nilai_rekomendasi": "0",
                            "memo_rekomendasi": "",
                            "data_tindak_lanjut": [
                                {
                                    "id": "20",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "21",
                                    "id_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "nilai_tindak_lanjut": "0",
                                    "memo_tindak_lanjut": "",
                                    "tindak_lanjut_no": "1",
                                    "tgl_tindak_lanjut": "0000-00-00"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var newArr = [];

for (let i of jsonObj.data) {
  for (let j of i.data_sebab) {
    for (let k of j.data_rekomendasi) {
      for (let l of k.data_tindak_lanjut) {
        newArr.push(l);
      }
    }
  }
}

jsonObj.data[0].data_sebab = newArr;

console.log(jsonObj);
```